# setTimeout within a for loop not executing the function passed to it

Tags: javascript, for-loop, settimeout

i'm trying to make a "console typing effect" with js, and in the next function i take the text of an element, then i use a "for" loop for slicing that text and paste in within with a delay.

After debugging the code in chrome i can see that javascript doesn't run the setTimeout... it just ignores it.

```
function type() {
    var text = document.querySelector('.console-effect').textContent;
    for (var i = 0; i <= text.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.querySelector('.console-effect').textContent = text.substr(0, i)
        }, 50);
    }
}
type();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it just ignores" setTimeout? Did you put a debug `console.log()` in there to see if the anonymous function is running? At any rate I can see immediately that you are going to have a problem. You need to "close over" the value of `i` for each iteration of the loop or else your code will not run as expected. Try wrapping the `setTimeout()` call in a closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `setTimeout`s are all executing at the same time, because the `for` loop does not wait for them to execute on each iteration. You have to delay each timeout using a value such as `50*i`.

Then, to preserve the value of `i` in this case, you'll need to use a closure. Otherwise, by the time your timeouts come to an end, the loop will be over, and `i` will be the final value, for all of them.

```js
var text = document.querySelector('.console-effect').textContent;

for (var i = 0; i <= text.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {  
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.querySelector('.console-effect').textContent = text.substr(0, i);
    }, 50*i);
  })(i);
}
```

```css
body{background: #333;}
.console-effect{color: #0f0; font-family: monospace; font-size: 2em;}
```

```html
<div class="console-effect">This is some example text</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, i understand now why i got the error. the only thing i didn't quite get is why do i use a closure around the setTimeout? i mean i read your answer but i still don't quite get it :/

Comment: @ShockE. Here are 2 examples to help you understand what happens to `i`. One without a closure: https://jsfiddle.net/zyLozkvp/ As you can see, once the loop is over, `i` is equal to `11` on the global scope. And one with a closure: https://jsfiddle.net/0L3oou1s/ . This time, as you have a closure (function), you are creating a new scope, where `i` is a whole new variable, in its own scope. Does that make it clearer?

Answer (score 1):

Is not a good idea to make functions inside a loop in Javascript, *I had bad experiences with it*.

This code done this way should work correctly:

```
function type() {
    var text = document.querySelector('.console-effect').textContent;
    var loopFunc = function(i) {
        return function() {
            document.querySelector('.console-effect').textContent = text.substr(0, i)
        };
    };
    for (var i = 0; i <= text.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(loopFunc(i), 50);
    }
}
type();
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't want to believe @blex, but he was correct about the scope. He was right on both points he made, but the closure stunned me. How have I never encountered this and been forced to puzzle my way out before?

So the idea here is that instead of scheduling a dozen or so calls to your function at the beginning, you only schedule the next call. After that one is called, it sees if it needs to schedule the next.

```js
function type() {
    var text = document.querySelector('.console-effect').textContent;
    var i = 0;
    var typeNext = function() {
        ++i;
        document.querySelector('.console-effect').textContent = text.substr(0, i);
        if(i < text.length) {
            setTimeout(typeNext, 50);
        }
    }
    setTimeout(typeNext, 50);
}
type();
```

```html
<span class="console-effect">This is a test</span>
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining me what the setTimeout at the end of the type() function does? If i understand right it calls the typeNext() the first time?

Comment: @ShockE. That is correct. After declaring the function, I delay 50ms then call it. Then, at the end of the method, I determine if it's necessary to delay and call again.

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = document.querySelector('.console-effect').textContent;
var index = 0;
setInterval(function(){
     document.querySelector('.console-effect').textContent = text.substr(0, index);
     if(index == text.lenght){
         clearInterval(this);
     }
index++;
},1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this.

```
function type() {
    var text = document.querySelector('.console-effect').textContent;
    document.querySelector('.console-effect').textContent = '';//clear content
    for (var i = 0; i <= text.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(function(j) {
            document.querySelector('.console-effect').textContent += text[j];// or .charAt(j)
        }, 50 * i, i);
        // 50 * i sets timeout for each iteration
        // i (3rd arg) passes to the inner function
    }
}
type();
```

Better version.

```
function type(text) {
    var textObj = document.querySelector('.console-effect');
    for (var i = 0; i <= text.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(function(ch) {
            textObj.textContent += ch;
        }, 50 * i, text[i]);
        // 50 * i sets timeout for each iteration
        // i (3rd arg) passes to the inner function
    }
}
type('.console-effect');
```

Answer (score 0):

a solution without 50*i, take a look at the css effect too. You problem is setTimeout is executed asynchronously (the 'control flow' doesn't wait for those 50ms), so they are fired all together with value i = text.length (if your text is small enough)

```
<p class="console-effect">console effects</p>
<script>
function type() {
        var i=0;
        var t = document.querySelector('.console-effect').textContent;
        var fn = setInterval(function() {
            print_text(++i,t,fn)
        }, 500);
}
function print_text(i,t,fn){
    if(i <= t.length){
                document.querySelector('.console-effect').textContent = t.substr(0, i)
    } else clearInterval(fn)
}
type();

</script>
<style>
@-webkit-keyframes blinker {  
  from { opacity: 1.0; }
  to { opacity: 0.0; }
}
.console-effect:after{
    content:'_';
    text-decoration: blink;
    -webkit-animation-name: blinker;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score -2):

setTimeout run only once(in your case after delay of 50ms).

For this purpose you should use setInterval

Comment: setInterval loops forever.

Comment: Not quite - you can have as many `setTimeout`s as you want, they are put on the stack independent of each other.

Comment: var index = 0;
setInterval(function(){
  console.log('learn JS')
  if(index == 10){
   clearInterval(this);
  }
index++;
},1000);